# HeadlessChrome bug - Uncaught [object Object] thrown

Tags: angular, google-chrome-headless

i'm using Karma to run my angular 7 test. I get this error after running the tests :
ProjectsService
    ✖ should be created
      HeadlessChrome 77.0.3865 (Linux 0.0.0)
    Uncaught [object Object] thrown

This is my karma.conf.js :

```
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
    //   require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-notify-reporter'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage/victi-aura'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary', 'clover'],
        fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
        thresholds: {
            statements: 30,
            lines: 30,
            branches: 30,
            functions: 30
          }
    },
    reporters: ['mocha', 'notify'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    singleRun: true,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

This is my test :

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CalendarDateLabelsService } from './calendar-date-labels.service';
import * as moment from 'moment';

describe('ProjectsService', () => {
    let service: CalendarDateLabelsService;
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [CalendarDateLabelsService]
        });
        service = TestBed.get(CalendarDateLabelsService);

    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });

    describe('updateWeeksNumber()', () => {
        it('should add correctly', () => {
            const firstDate = moment(service.currentDate);
            service.updateWeeksNumber(1);
            expect(firstDate.diff(service.currentDate, 'week')).toBe(-1);
            service.updateWeeksNumber(-2);
            expect(firstDate.diff(service.currentDate, 'week')).toBe(1);
        });
    });
});
```

I know there is another question about this error but I have not found solutions in the answers provided. I already tried to delete the node_module directory and install it again but didn't work.